# Function that returns array of array combinations

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, probability

I'm trying to make a `_.combinations` function (underscore mixin) that takes three parameters `arr, pockets, duplicates`. Here's a test that I designed to show how the behavior should be.

```
expect(_.combinations([1, 2], 1, false)).to.be.equal([[1],[2]])
expect(_.combinations([1, 2], 1, true)).to.be.equal([[1],[2]])
expect(_.combinations([1, 2, 3], 2, false)).to.be.equal([[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]])
expect(_.combinations([1, 2, 3], 2, true)).to.be.equal([[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[2,1],[3,1],[3,2]])
expect(_.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, false)).to.be.equal([[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,1,4],[2,3,4],[3,4,1]])
expect(_.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, true)).to.be.equal([[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,1,4],[2,3,1],[2,3,4],[3,1,2],[3,4,1],[3,4,2],[4,1,2],[4,1,3],[4,2,3]])
```

I was wondering before I go and create this function if it existed within a library already. Perhaps this specific function already has a name that I'm not familiar with.

Is there something out there that does this?

Comment: As a starting point, you can make use of a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) function (just search for it; plenty of people have written functions for it) to retrieve the combinations. From there it should be relatively simple to filter based on your other arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dankogai/js-combinatorics/master/combinatorics.js) library has good function. I think its pretty much got what you need.

```
var combinatorics=require('/path/to/combinatorics');

var a = [1,2,3];

var ans1=combinatorics.permutation(a,2); 
console.log(ans1.toArray());// [[1,2],[2,1],[1,3],[3,1],[2,3],[3,2]] like when duplicates is set to true


var ans2=combinatorics.combination(a,2); 
console.log(ans2.toArray());//[[1,2],[2,1],[1,3],[3,1],[2,3],[3,2]] like when duplicates is set to false
```

Comment: This looks amazing I'm pretty sure this has everything that I want :)